# Does god listen to our prayers when we talk to him?

Tags: prayer

When we pray to god (Bhagwan), does he listen to our prayers ?
Does he listen to us when we talk to him ?

Does he understand any language in which we talk to him ? Or Only Sanskrit ?

Is is necessary to clearly spell our talks/prayers from our mouth in order for him to listen ?
Or If we talk in our mind (mann) , he listens to them as well ?

Comment: Yep, since Ishvara is omnipresent. Will he fulfill the prayer? That depends on your Karma. In fact, the reason for Avataaras are prayers. When enough prayer karma is accumulated, then the Avataara descends at a suitable time and location. If you haven't done a lot of bad Karma, then your prayer can be fulfilled, if you pray enough. If you have, then no amount of prayer will save you, look at purushartha.
Prayer is always good to do, for yourself and for everyone on earth as it adds an extra bit, each time to the pot of divine help, that will fructify at a suitable time, when the pot fills up.